# How to get list of sub-targets which got hit in a makefile?

Tags: bash, gcc, makefile

I have a makefile as follows,

```
all: target1
        @echo "$(USER)"

target1: target2
        @echo "$(HOME)"

target2:
        @echo "$(SHELL)"
```

If I execute `make all`, I will get some output as expected. But is there way to know which targets got hit when ran that command. In this case, `make all` invoked `target1, target2`. If I had done `make target1` then only `target2` would have invoked.

One very bad solution I did was adding echo statement in all my targets as follows,

```
all: target1
        @echo "Running $@"
        @echo "$(USER)"

target1: target2
        @echo "Running $@"
        @echo "$(HOME)"

target2:
        @echo "Running $@"
        @echo "$(SHELL)"
```

Is there any good solution without having to add such prints?

Comment: Since you don't say what's "bad" about adding echo statements, or what you want to do with the information about which targets were run, we can't be much help.  I _can_ say that there's no way from within make itself to know that: there's no make variable or function that tracks that information.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, when you run

```
make target1
```

You should see first target2 then target1 executed..

If you want to see how `make` orders the targets and executes them, you can run `make -d`.

Alternatively, if you want to see the shell command lines that are executed without actually running them, the option `--dry-run` exists but does not indicate the actual target names.